# Help with proportional editing

Tags: modeling

I am working on a tutorial in Blender where I am trying to model a frosted doughnut, but when I try using proportional editing on a single vertex, I move the whole mesh down. What do I do?
[image]

Comment: Use mouse scroll wheel to decrease the influence range.

Comment: The version of Blender I use is 2.9.

Answer (score 1):

How big is your "proportional editing" brush. I find the Brush can get so big you can't see it in the viewport and it is affecting more than you want. Hold down "S" to "S"cale and scroll your mouse wheel to adjust the brush size

[image]

Comment: I have Blender 2.9 on a laptop.

Comment: I need help with this.

Comment: "PageUp PageDown" buttons will adjust the brush size as well. Do you have Preferences > Input  > Keyboard > Emulate NumPad checked? It helps if you don't have a 101 keyboard.

Comment: Is there any way to force the brush size to the smallest possible setting with a single keypress (where one could then scale the brush size upward as needed fairly easily, as this would put the brush size very close to the desired range without much work)? It is so tiresome to have to do this tedious brush shrinking operation every time the brush is too big for the current view. In extreme cases, it can take a while to get it into view. This is especially annoying when using a tablet.